# Pandas difference between `.astype('categorical') and `pd.Category(...)`

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataset with a string column (name: 14) that I want to convert to interpret as a categorical feature. As far as I know there're two ways to do that:

```py
pd.Categorical(data[14])
data[14].astype('category')
```

While both of these produce result with the same `.dtype`: `CategoricalDtype(categories=[' <=50K', ' >50K'], ordered=False)` they're not the same.

Calling `.describe()` on the results they produce different outputs. The first one outputs information about individual categories while the second one (`astype(..)`) results in typical describe output with count, unique, top, freq, and name, listing `dtype: object`.

My question is, then, why / how do they differ?

---

It's this dataset: http://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/datasets/Adult

```py
data = pd.read_csv("./adult/adult.data", header=None)

pd.Categorical(data[14]).describe()
data[14].astype('category').describe()

pd.Categorical(data[14]).dtype
data[14].astype('category').dtype
```

Comment: I'm not an expert pandas user, but looking [at the documentation on Categorical data](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/categorical.html) it seems like `pd.Series(pd.Categorical(data[14]))` might be what you are looking for. The return types are different, `Categorical` does not return a `Series`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As [Bakuriu points out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55012142/pandas-difference-between-astypecategorical-and-pd-category/55012352#comment96779123_55012142), `type(pd.Categorical(data[14]))` is `Categorical`, while
`type(data[14].astype('category'))` is `Series`:

```
import pandas as pd
data = pd.read_csv("./adult/adult.data", header=None)

cat = pd.Categorical(data[14])
ser = data[14].astype('category')
print(type(cat))
# pandas.core.arrays.categorical.Categorical
print(type(ser))
# pandas.core.series.Series
```

The behavior of `describe()` differs
because [`Categorical.describe`](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/blob/master/pandas/core/arrays/categorical.py#L2359) is defined differently than [`Series.describe`](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/blob/master/pandas/core/generic.py#L9502).

Whenever you call `Categorical.describe()`, you'll get `count` and `freq` per category:

```
In [174]: cat.describe()
Out[174]: 
            counts    freqs
categories                 
 <=50K       24720  0.75919
 >50K         7841  0.24081
```

and whenever you call `Series.describe()` on a categorical Series, [you'll get `count`, `unique`, `top` and `freq`](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/blob/master/pandas/core/generic.py#L9605). Note that `count` and `freq` have a different meaning here too:

```
In [175]: ser.describe()
Out[175]: 
count      32561
unique         2
top        <=50K
freq       24720
Name: 14, dtype: object
```